# Jumpy scrolling in Firefox in jQuery slimScroll 1.3.3 plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slimscroll

I am using the [jQuery SlimScroll Plugin](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll).

They have a `div` element and this element content is dynamically loaded via ajax call. I am using slimScroll on that `div` and tried to start from bottom.
The slimscrollbar start at the bottom but the inside scrollcontent jump a little bit up.

Its work perfectly on Google Chrome, Safari, only problem in Firefox. Here is my jquery code.

```
 $el = $('#myDiv');
 $el.slimScroll({
    height: '350px',
    start: 'bottom',
    alwaysVisible: true,
    allowPageScroll: false
});
```

Comment: So, what happens with Firefox ? Please describe if you want any answers.

Comment: Is javascrpt enabled in mozilla firefox browser?

Comment: #kebs, thanks for your reply, In Firefox, the scrollBar show at the bottom but the htmlContent is jump to above position(i.e. 100px up from bottom) from bottom. For that, I cannot see the last message, For seeing the last content I need to scrool down again. But In Crome, the scroolbar show on the bottom as well as inner content also show the last section.

Comment: #joshi, thanks for your reply, yes javascript is enabled in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

its very simple you just have to comment this line

`this.addEventListener('MozMousePixelScroll', _onWheel, false );` on the file 'slimscroll.js' and it will work for all the browser hope this helps you !